# The name 'mode' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

So my teacher gave me this as homework on piece of paper just to copy and improve, but the thing is the code isn't even launching.Got 2 problems in error list:

1. **The name 'mode' does not exist in the current context**
2. **Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement. ( for this one: label1.Top + label1.Top + speed;)**

He wrote on paper that this code has to launch. Maybe my mistake anywhere ?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int mode = 0;
        int speed = 5;

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (mode == 0)
        {
            label1.Left = label1.Left + speed;
            if (label1.Left > 240)
              mode == 1;
        }
        if (mode = 1)
        {
            label1.Top + label1.Top + speed;
            if (label1.Top > 240)
                mode == 2;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The assignment is to fix the code so that it will launch. If we just give you the answer, you'll miss out on figuring out the problems yourself. It sounds like this assignment is not just about knowing what the code should be, but getting practice in working through the troubleshooting process.

Comment: make those variables as global, currently it is defined inside the scope of `Form1_Load` so it will not be available outside of that block

Comment: Hints: (1) `mode` is created in `Form1_Load` and destroyed on exit from that procedure. You need a "class-level" variable if you want to share among procedures. (2) Look at the difference between the non-working mode 1 code and the working mode 2 command.

Comment: Change ***label1.Top + label1.Top + speed;*** to ***label1.Top = label1.Top + speed;***